# setEncoding Error when Serving OpenFin on MAC

Tags: node.js, openfin

I am seeing `Fatal error: Cannot read property 'setEncoding' of undefined` on my Mac when running through the OpenFin tutorial here => https://openfin.co/create-your-first-application/

It's happening when calling `> grunt serve`.

Answer (score -1):

This bug was fixed on the latest version of the openfin-launcher, please re-install that package:

`npm install openfin-launcher@1.3.3`

Additionally change the version form "stable" to "beta" as Mac support is still experimental.